# LDA for Topic Modeling in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, lda, topic-modeling

I am new to Python, and I am trying to use the LDA package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lda). I have a list of titles and topics each one is related to. However, I have no clue how to use the package in the first place. I have read the documentation for package but it is vague. There is no information about the input structure and everything. Is there anyone who has used it before? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try Gensim, a well documented Python package that comes with easy to use [tutorials](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/).

Answer (score 0):

you can also look into [Rosetta](https://github.com/columbia-applied-data-science/rosetta) - it's aimed at text processing in general but has a VW LDA step by step [tutorial](https://github.com/columbia-applied-data-science/rosetta/blob/master/examples/vw_helpers.md).

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, as the info goes away if the link changes.  Its better to post the essentials (as well)